# Is the $\infty$-category $N_{dg}(\mathrm{Ch}(\mathcal{A}))$ presentable?

Tags: homological-algebra, infinity-categories, higher-algebra

(See Jacob Lurie's ["Higher Algebra"](https://www.math.ias.edu/%7Elurie/papers/HA.pdf), section 1.3.5 for context.)

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a Grothendieck abelian category. Then the stable $\infty$-category $\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{A})$ is a localisation of the dg-nerve $N_{dg}(\mathrm{Ch}(\mathcal{A}))$ by *Higher Algebra* Proposition 1.3.5.13, and it is presentable according to *Higher Algebra* Proposition 1.3.5.21, since it is underlying a combinatorial model category.

My question is: what can we say about $N_{dg}(\mathrm{Ch}(\mathcal{A}))$ itself? Is it presentable?

As far as I can understand, the introduction of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.11388.pdf seems to suggest that there is an underlying model structure which is not combinatorial but **accessible**, although I am not sure if this is enough to conclude...

Answer (score 11):

This fails already with the category of abelian groups. If the dg-nerve of the dg-category of chain complexes of abelian groups were presentable, then the associated triangulated category would be well generated in the sense of Neeman in his book *Triangulated categories* (Annals of Math. Studies, Vol. 148, 2001); this is easy to deduce from [Krause's characterization](https://eudml.org/doc/49219) together with section 1.4.4 of Lurie's *Higher Algebra*. But in appendix E of his book, Neeman proves that the triangulated category of chain complexes up to chain homotopy equivalences does not have a generating set (Lemma E.3.2 page 438), which provides a definitive obstruction against presentability. He also proves that the opposite category is not well generated, by the way (but this is easier).

Comment: Is the homotopy category of chain complexes (of abelian groups) accessible?

Comment: No it is not (since it is cocomplete that would imply it is presentable, which it is not, as I explain above). The *adjuncion* between the homotopy category and the derived category is accessible though (i.e. the right adjoint of the localization functor by quasi-isomorphisms has a right adjoint that preserves $\kappa$-filtered colimits for $\kappa$ big enough). This is essentially what is proved (in the language of model structures) in the paper of Lyne Moser mentioned in the question.

Answer (score -1):

If $\mathcal{A}$ is a small Grothendieck abelian category, one could possibly argue this way: recall that presentable means accessible and closed under small colimits.

Since $\mathcal{A}$ is small, the $\infty$-category $N_{\mathrm{dg}}(\mathrm{Ch}(\mathcal{A}))$ is essentially small by *HTT* Proposition 5.4.1.2 (1) and admits small colimits, so it is idempotent complete, hence by *HTT* Corollary 5.4.3.6 it is presentable.

Comment: An abelian Grothendieck category has small colimits. If it is small, by the "uncheatable lemma" from this answer https://mathoverflow.net/a/365951/1017 it would a partially ordered set and an abelian category, hence equivalent to zero. In particular, it would be presentable, that is true, but for rather trivial reasons!

Comment: Giulio Lo Monaco has shown "the uncheatable" for infinity categories here: http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/37/5/37-05.pdf