# Why do we care about small sets?

Tags: ct.category-theory, set-theory, foundations

I have been a user of category theory for a long time. I recently started studying a rigorous treatment of categories within ZFC+U. Then I become suspecting the effect of the smallness of sets.

We first fix notations.
Let $\mathbb{U}$ be a Grothendieck universe.
A set $x$ is called a *$\mathbb{U}$-set* if $x\in \mathbb{U}$.
A set is said to be *$\mathbb{U}$-small* if it is isomorphic to a $\mathbb{U}$-set.
We denote by $\operatorname{Set}_{\mathbb{U}}$ the category of $\mathbb{U}$-sets.
A category is called a *locally $\mathbb{U}$-category* (resp. *locally $\mathbb{U}$-small*) if its hom-sets are $\mathbb{U}$-sets (resp. $\mathbb{U}$-small).

There seem to be various advantages to a set being a $\mathbb{U}$-set.
For example,
$\mathbb{U}$-sets belong to $\operatorname{Set}_{\mathbb{U}}$ by the definition.
It is important when we construct the Yoneda embedding
$\mathcal{C} \to \operatorname{Fun}(\mathcal{C}^{\operatorname{op}},\operatorname{Set}_{\mathbb{U}})$
of locally $\mathbb{U}$-categories.
In contrast, we cannot construct such an embedding canonically for locally $\mathbb{U}$-small categories.

In various books, the fact that a set is small is treated as an important thing.
For example, let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category.
Then its *Grothendieck group* $K_0(\mathcal{A})$ is defined by the free abelian group generated by the isomorphism classes $[X]$ of objects modulo the *Euler relation*:
$[B]=[A]+[C]$ if there exists a short exact sequence $0\to A \to B\to C\to 0$.
In many books (for example, Weibel`s K-book),
the skeletally $\mathbb{U}$-smallness is imposed on $\mathcal{A}$.
That is, suppose that
the set of isomorphism classes of objects of $\mathcal{A}$ is $\mathbb{U}$-small.
This guarantees that $K_0(\mathcal{A})$ is a $\mathbb{U}$-small abelian group.
However, how does this benefit us?

Note:
a category is a tuple $(\mathcal{C}_0,\mathcal{C}_1,s,t,e,\circ)$ of sets and maps satifying some conditions.
Thus I think that the Grothendieck group can be defined
without imposing any conditions on an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: It is not completely clear to me what you are asking, I don't really see a question in your text - are you asking how the notion of $\mathbb{U}$-small is important/usefull compared to the notion of $\mathbb{U}$-set, or are you asking how both notions are important?

Comment: I understood the question to be “why not just use a large abelian category when constructing the Grothendieck group $K_0(A)$“? And the answer is “because set theory bites“.

Comment: @SimonHenry I would like to know why we should bother to prove whether a set is U-small in various situations.

Comment: @Andrej: While I have yet to experience such biting from set theory (maybe set theory can smell fear?), and while I can't say that the question that you understood here makes a lot of sense to me, when it comes to largeness issues, it's usually the logic that bites, not the set theory.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: It's probably not important, but my point was that this is an example of “naive set theory gone wrong”.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First, it is important to distinguish between the problem related to the foundation you are using from the problems that are inherent to category theory.

For example, the distinction between $\mathbb{U}$-small and $\mathbb{U}$-set is something that has to do with the set-theoretic foundation - in category theory, we don't consider properties that distinguish isomorphic objects so the notion of $\mathbb{U}$-set don't make sense (only $\mathbb{U}$-small).

Now, from the category-theoretic perspective, the only important thing is simply to keep track of what "size" are the objects you work with ("small" vs "large" though in some contexts one might need more than two sizes, "very large", etc...).

The problem isn't that you are not allowed to make some constructions - there are foundations that let you do pretty much everything you want with as many different sizes as you want - but only that you want to know in what categories the constructions you are making take values - do they produce small sets, large sets, "very large sets" etc... Some foundation might prevent you from doing some construction of course - but if you only focus on things that are "foundation independent" you can just change foundation if you run in this sort of problems - we do that very often.

To come back to your specific problem, It is completely fine to consider the $K_0$ of a "large" abelian category and get a "large" group. As pointed out by Andrej Brauer, in some foundations this might cause problems, but there definitely are foundations that can handle that sort of thing fine - for example the one you are talking about where everything is a set and size issues are handled with Grothendieck universe is indeed completely fine with this.

The thing is, if you build a large $K_0$, then you have a large group, but it is not an element of your "category of groups". If you want to make the $K_0$ construction into a functor you have to put some kind of size restriction on the category you apply it to. And if you want the category of "large group" to be a set, you are really going to need some kind of size restriction...

Now, there are many examples where not keeping track of size actually leads to problems. The most common is probably in the definition of limits and colimits: when one say that a category has all limits or colimits we always mean that it has all **small** limits or colimits. In fact it is a theorem that if a category has products (or coproduct) indexed by set of the same size as itself then it is a poset ! So when doing argument involving limits and colimits you always need to make sure the diagram you are taking limits and colimits on are small.

For example, the following argument is false because we are not careful with the size problems:

**Fake Proposition:** Every category with limits has an initial object.

**Fake proof:**  If $C$ has all limits then one can take the limit $L$ of the identity functor of $C \to C$. We will show that $L$ is an initial object. By construction, for every object $X \in C$ there is a map $f_X:L \to X$ and for every arrow $v:X \to Y$ we have $v f_X = f_Y$. Then for Every other arrow $k:L \to X$ we have $k f_L = f_X$. In particular, taking $k=f_X$ you get $f_X f_L = f_X$. It follows that $f_X f_L = f_X Id_L$ for all object $X$, and hence by the uniqueness part of the universal property of the limits $f_L = Id_L$, hence the equation above gives $k=f_X$ so there is a unique map $L \to X$ for each object $X$.

*Note:* The correct argument here of course show that if a category has limits indexed by itself then it has an initial object, but in traditional ZFC foundation, category having all limits of their own size are posets as mentioned above (There are however alternative foundation incompatible with ZFC where this result apply to categories that aren't posets).

Another situation is when building adjoint functors. It is pretty frequent that some would-be adjoint functors we want to exist actually don't because they take values in categories of "large objects" (for example large set or large group instead of the category of groups and sets) instead of the domain of the functor they are an adjoint of. This happens for example with the forgetful functor from complete boolean algebra to the category of sets - where the would-be left adjoint applied to any infinite set gives rise a something the size of the universe.

Of course in the case of $K_0$ you have two options: either only apply it to small categories, or you apply it to "large" categories, and consider that it takes values in the category of "large groups" - but then you need one more size because the category of "large groups" is itself "very large".

In the case of $K_0$ the reason why everybody makes the first choice and not the second is because in practice the $K_0$ construction is only interesting for categories like "finitely presented modules" or "finite-dimensional bundle/vector space" which are all essentially small categories.
As soon as you allow infinite dimensional objects in your category you end up with objects satisfying equation of the form $X \oplus X =X $ and $X \oplus Y = X$ for $Y$ finite-dimensional, which makes your $K_0$ group trivial. One can probably engineer interesting examples of large abelian categories with interesting $K_0$, but all the naive examples (like all groups, all bundles or all vector spaces) have trivial $K_0$ for this reason.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It resolves some of my concerns. I have a question. As you said, almost all interesting categories are essentially small in the context of  Grothendieck groups. Thus I want to construct K_0 as a functor from the category of essentially U-small abelian categories to the category of U-small abelian groups. However, I think that we cannot consider the set of all U-small abelian groups. Is it natural to fix a universe V containing U and consider the category of U-small abelian groups belonging to V?

Comment: I would like to know if you know of any literature that has a good discussion of this kind.

Comment: Regarding your first question - from a purely category theoretic point of view it is completely fine to consider the category of U-small sets. In the sort of foundation you are using, one needs an additional level of care: you indeed need to consider a second universe $V$ such that $U \in V$, and consider the category of $V$-sets that are $U$-small. The resulting category technically depends on $V$, but not in an essential way: if you replace $V$ by another universe $W$ you get an equivalent categories (because they are both equivalent to the category of $U$-sets).

Comment: Regarding litterature - I don't know a place that focuses on the kind of problems that arise out of size issue. They tend to pop-up here and there in isolated way. Mike shulman has a survey paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.1279) on the various kind of set theoretic foundation that can be use to deal with issue, but I'm not sure that is what you are after. The fact that there are many different foundation that can be used to deal with these problems mean there is no unified account of this sort of things.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was very helpful for me!

Comment: @LOCOAS There are some other MO questions which discuss some of these issues, e.g., [When size matters in category theory for the working mathematician](https://mathoverflow.net/q/365947) and [Reflection principle vs universes](https://mathoverflow.net/a/382670/).

Comment: To name drop a relevant foundation that can go beyond "small, big, very big", there is the "Tarski–Grothendieck set theory", which is basically "ZFC + every set is inside of a universe" (note that the TG set theory uses Tarski-classes, and not Grothendieck-universes, the main difference between the 2 is that Tarski-classes implies AC, so ZF+every set is inside a universe does not prove AC while ZF+every set is inside of a Tarski-class does implies choice)

Answer (score 11):

Given a class $C$ and an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $C$ we often wish to construct the quotient $C/{\sim}$. However, from the perspective of ZFC this is not such a straightforward things to do, because the elements of $C/{\sim}$ ought to be set-sized, but they may be proper classes. A proper class may not be an element of another class.

For instance, if $C$ is the category of abelian groups and $\sim$ is isomorphism, then the equivalence class of the trivial group would be a proper class because there are as many trivial groups as there are singleton sets.

The solution is to either curb the size of $C$ by requiring it to be $\mathbb{U}$-small, or to use [Scott's trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott%27s_trick): instead of working with the class-sized equivalence class $[x]_{\sim}$, we use as its representative the set $[x]_{\sim} \cap V_\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is the minimum [rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Rank_of_a_set&redirect=no) of elements of $[x]_{\sim}$ and $V_\alpha$ is the $\alpha$-th level of the cummulative hierarchy.

In a category-theoretic setting, where notions of size appear in many situations, it is more practical to require $\mathbb{U}$-smallness than to rely heavily on the cummulative hierarchy (which may not even be available in some versions of category theory).

Comment: As I write at the end of the text, I only consider categories such that ObC and MorC are sets. For example, we consider the category of abelian groups belonging to $\mathbb{U}$ instead of the category of all abelian groups. In such a case, I think that the problem which you described would not arise. I am a beginner in these matters, so I apologise if I have made any major mistakes.

Comment: That's precisely what I was trying to explain: if you *didn't* consider $\mathbb{U}$-small groups, *then* you would have a problem. And that is my answer to the question "why do we consider small sets"?

Comment: I think it is not optimal to answer the question with classes, since the setting is ZFC + universes. Here everything is a set, and some of the issues do not arise resp. need to be formulated differently.

Comment: The way I understood the question was "why do we bother with smallness?". Assuming that's correct, how would you explain what goes wrong if we don't bother with smallness, without recalling the usual problems that arise in naive set theory?